# Hadoop 3.1.0 ports to open

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ports

OK -- I managed to cobble together three CentOS 7 laptops,
install Hadoop 3.1.0, and get all three nodes running.
Good for me.

SO...what ports are required to be open on all
the various nodes?

Checking http://namenode:9870 the nice
"Datanode Information" page appears and shows all
three nodes up and running.  Additionally,
running the command "hdfs dfsadmin -report" on any
node shows all nodes running.

HOWEVER...checking the "Nodes of the Cluster" page
at http://namenode:8088 only shows the namenode...

Should I see all the data nodes on this page as well?
Wondering if I need to open some ports or if my understanding
of the "Nodes of the Cluster" requires an update...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a site which lists all the default ports in a Hadoop cluster configuration.

http://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/default-ports-used-by-hadoop-services-hdfs-mapreduce-yarn

Comment: All these ports are open on all machines in the cluster, STILL having the same issue.